# Upgrading to EF6 in entire solution

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget, entity-framework-6

I would like to upgrade from EF4 to 6 and I'm looking for easiest way to update references.

Right now, references are not from NuGet but from custom location. My sln is quite big and its contain a lot of projects which have EF model.

Question is,
do I need run

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```

for each project inside sln manually? It would be nice to have possibility to run this command for all project with EF at once.

Thank you.

Comment: Recommend the Julie Lerman articles http://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/magazine/dn786902(en-us).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the command line you can run something like the following:

```
Update-package -Id Entityframework -ProjectName xxx
```

However on solution level I always find it quite easier to do it using UI:

1. Manage NuGet Packages
2. Search for EntityFramework
3. Install it on one of your projects
4. Go to Installed Packages  + Manage
5. Tick all the projects you want to have the EF reference